# Internet speed really slow in debian bookworm kde but not in Windows

Tags: debian, networking, wifi

On windows browsing speed is great but on debian bookworm browsing speed is really slow, have referred many posts online but still can't figure out why.

Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2a02 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 27c6:639c Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Goodix USB2.0 MISC
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04ca:00ac Lite-On Technology Corp. Dell Wireless Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `dmesg | grep iwl`:

```
[    2.568527] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.572565] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode
[    2.572582] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.572599] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[    2.572948] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
[    2.573082] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
[    2.573100] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-72.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.816789] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x351
[    2.946843] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF HR B3, rfid=0x10a100
[    3.012457] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 20:c1:9b:08:5e:62
[    3.029079] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
[   12.718460] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[   12.718635] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[   12.718831] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
```

Output of `dmesg --level=emerg,crit,err,warn`:

```
[    0.082714] ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
[    0.370975] pnp 00:05: disabling [mem 0xc0000000-0xcfffffff] because it overlaps 0000:00:02.0 BAR 9 [mem 0x00000000-0xdfffffff 64bit pref]
[    0.664921] hpet_acpi_add: no address or irqs in _CRS
[    0.671343] i8042: Warning: Keylock active
[    0.916540] wmi_bus wmi_bus-PNP0C14:02: WQBC data block query control method not found
[    0.932482] pci 10000:e0:1c.4: Primary bus is hard wired to 0
[    0.933004] pci 10000:e0:1c.4: Primary bus is hard wired to 0
[    1.013738] usb: port power management may be unreliable
[    1.083995] pcieport 10000:e0:1c.4: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[    1.083996] pcieport 10000:e0:1c.4: PCI INT A: no GSI
[    1.167666] pcieport 10000:e0:1c.4: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
[    1.167670] nvme 10000:e1:00.0: PCI INT A: not connected
[    2.197783] device-mapper: core: CONFIG_IMA_DISABLE_HTABLE is disabled. Duplicate IMA measurements will not be recorded in the IMA log.
[    2.489453] dell_smm_hwmon: unable to get SMM Dell signature
[    2.516777] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0xfedc0000-0xfedcdfff], which spans more than pnp 00:05 [mem 0xfedc0000-0xfedc7fff]
[    2.516784] caller __uncore_imc_init_box+0xc4/0x120 [intel_uncore] mapping multiple BARs
[    2.572582] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.572948] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
[    2.572968] firmware_class: See https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware
[    2.573082] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
[    2.816875] thermal thermal_zone5: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[    3.160383] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: Parent card not yet available, widget card binding deferred
[    3.276770] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: sink widget AIF1TX overwritten
[    3.276782] snd_hda_codec_realtek ehdaudio0D0: ASoC: source widget AIF1RX overwritten
[    3.276996] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget hifi3 overwritten
[    3.277004] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget hifi2 overwritten
[    3.277011] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget hifi1 overwritten
[    3.277018] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: source widget Codec Output Pin1 overwritten
[    3.277024] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget Codec Input Pin1 overwritten
[    3.277033] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget Analog Codec Playback overwritten
[    3.277041] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget Digital Codec Playback overwritten
[    3.277049] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: sink widget Alt Analog Codec Playback overwritten
[    3.277058] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: source widget Analog Codec Capture overwritten
[    3.277066] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: source widget Digital Codec Capture overwritten
[    3.277074] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: ASoC: source widget Alt Analog Codec Capture overwritten
[    3.277093] skl_hda_dsp_generic skl_hda_dsp_generic: hda_dsp_hdmi_build_controls: no PCM in topology for HDMI converter 3
[    8.085738] kauditd_printk_skb: 26 callbacks suppressed
[   12.718460] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[   12.718635] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
[   12.718831] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0x707
```

Output of `lsmod | grep rtl`:

```
btrtl                  28672  1 btusb
bluetooth             954368  44 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
```

Output of `iwconfig` :

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp0s20f3  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"ZTE_2.4G_xGkTMR"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.2 GHz  Access Point: B8:DD:71:F7:1B:B8   
          Bit Rate=866.7 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=58/70  Signal level=-52 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:24   Missed beacon:0

docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

Output of `neofetch`:

```
       _,met$$$$$gg.          krish@debian 
    ,g$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$P.       ------------ 
  ,g$$P"     """Y$$.".        OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64 
 ,$$P'              `$$$.     Host: Inspiron 15 5518 
',$$P       ,ggs.     `$$b:   Kernel: 6.1.0-10-amd64 
`d$$'     ,$P"'   .    $$$    Uptime: 14 mins 
 $$P      d$'     ,    $$P    Packages: 2703 (dpkg), 18 (flatpak) 
 $$:      $$.   -    ,d$$'    Shell: bash 5.2.15 
 $$;      Y$b._   _,d$P'      Resolution: 1920x1080 
 Y$$.    `.`"Y$$$$P"'         DE: Plasma 5.27.5 
 `$$b      "-.__              WM: KWin 
  `Y$$                        Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK3] 
   `Y$$.                      Icons: Win11-blue [Plasma], Win11-blue [GTK2/3] 
     `$$b.                    Terminal: konsole 
       `Y$$b.                 CPU: 11th Gen Intel i5-11320H (8) @ 4.500GHz 
          `"Y$b._             GPU: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] 
              `"""            Memory: 2809MiB / 15732MiB
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You've shown `lsusb` output but your Wi-Fi adapter is most likely connected via PCI-E. I presume it's Intel's AX201. Please edit your question and at the very least post `dmesg | grep iwl` and `dmesg --level=emerg,crit,err,warn` outputs.

Comment: Hi @ArtemS.Tashkinov, thanks for the response, I have updated the post as requested. Please inform If any more information in needed, I am happy to share

Comment: What's your MTU? Do: `ip l | grep $(ip r | awk '/default/ {print $5}' ) | awk '{print $2, $4, $5}'`.

Comment: @waltinator MTU:
wlp0s20f3: mtu 1500

Comment: There's nothing unusual in your logs, they look OK'ish. Can you confirm Linux is a lot slower on e.g. https://fast.com and https://speedtest.net ? Can you post the numbers? Lastly, make sure both OSes are under the same conditions. For instance, you could be using VPN under Linux and of course that could lead to much worse results.

Comment: It's fine in speed tests but surfing speeds are really slow. I am getting about 300mbps of upload and 200mbps of download in speedtest.net.
And this problem is browser independent. I have tried Firefox, chrome, edge, and Brave. And I don't use any VPN.

Answer (score 0):

The `MTU` (Maximum Transmission Unit) is the size of the largest packet that can be sent in a single network transmission. If a packet exceeds the  `MTU` of a link, the data must be split into multiple packets (fragmented). These multiple packets must be sent over the link, received, acknowledged, and reassembled at the far end. If your link is misconfigured, and you have to fragment every packet you send, your actual data transfer rate drops.

Ethernet (wired)  networks use an `MTU` of 1500 bytes.

Due to additional per packet overhead for WiFi (8 bytes PPPoE header), WiFi uses an `MTU` of 1492.

Your `MTU` should be set by your DHCP server, check your router's config.

You can set your own `MTU` (setting does not persist over restarts) with

```
sudo ip link set dev wlp0s20f3 mtu 1492
```

Read man `ip ip-link`.

Comment: Is it written anywhere Wifi uses PPoE? In OP's question? In Wifi specs? While I don't rule out there's a MTU problem, I don't understand why you're writing that Wifi uses PPPoE.

Comment: I've not seen PPPoE being used in conjunction with Wi-Fi ... ever. :-)